# How to draw this line diagram with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, line

I'm attaching a sketch. If it's possible to have the letters in the middle of the dimension lines, even better. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,0)--(12,0);
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,2,5,10,12}
{\draw (\X,0.1) -- (\X,-0.1) coordinate (\Y);}
\draw[latex-latex] (1|- 0,-0.5) -- (2|- 0,-0.5) node[fill=white,midway]{$a$};
\draw[latex-latex] (4|- 0,-0.5) -- (5|- 0,-0.5) node[fill=white,midway]{$b$};
\draw[latex-latex] (1|- 0,-1) -- (3|- 0,-1) node[fill=white,midway]{$c$};
\draw[latex-latex] (3|- 0,-1) -- (5|- 0,-1) node[fill=white,midway]{$d$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I upvoted but I didn't notice the green check mark. It should be accepted now.